# Stop long running SSRS Subscription Job

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, jobs

Anyone know how to stop a long running SSRS Subscription Job that is supposed to be pushing reports out to a UNC path but it had a bug and it is not pushing anything however it is still checking but failing on each row of the dataset.

The following is the closest I have to finding a solution:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce552f9b-c1c5-4a23-bd1d-0525d9342449/stop-a-running-ssrs-subscription?forum=sqlreportingservices

Which isn't really that close as on the server box itself I was able to logon to however their are no jobs showing so there is nothing to cancel.
I also tried restarting the SSRS server via Configuration Manager but to know avail.

I should also mention I prefer not to delete the Subscription and see if it works and create a new one but looks like I might have to try that.

Answer (score 2):

The link is correct.

In SSMS click Connect and "Reporting Services":
[image]

Expand the newly added node and expand the Jobs node.  Right click the required job and click cancel.  If there are no Jobs displayed then no jobs are running.

Comment: What part of "... no Jobs showing ..." did you not understand. You have provided an answer I have already mentioned in my question

Comment: You said "Anyone know how to stop a long running SSRS Subscription Job ".  Then you said "their are no jobs showing".  These CANNOT both be true.  If there are no jobs showing, there are no jobs running.  If you are convinced there is a job running, then it will be showing.

Comment: Plus " I also tried restarting the SSRS server via Configuration Manager but to know avail.".  This WILL cancel all running jobs, so the job you say is running and cannot be cancelled WILL DEFINITELY be cancelled by restarting the SSRS server.

Comment: Also comments such as "What part of "... no Jobs showing ..." did you not understand." are unrequired and unpleasant.  Try "Perhaps you misunderstood, or did you mean something else".  This will keep the forum a pleasant place for everyone.  Thanks.

Comment: I am learning this as I go so it is news to me as much as it is to you so I can understand what you are saying so apologies however what I saying is still correct that the job continues. Let me explain in further comment

Comment: The job runs obviously but then finishes. Creates a background event task that is not seen in the jobs list because as I believe the job triggers an event and then finishes immediately. The step: exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='84e58a7b-69c4-4048-a26b-9fa010b68bb1'

Comment: This event that is triggered by the step of the job there must be away of stopping it. I know it is still running because I can refresh my browser on the subscription page any number of times and see the progress increasing. Not that I checked if the task is halted when the SSRS server is stopped but it is certainly still running when I start it again and the job (or should I say event) has not stopped or restarted) and the progress continues as if nothing has happened.

Comment: And I can confirm deleting the subscription and creating a new one is the only practical way I know of stopping the job/event however, would be nice to know if there was a process behind the event that I can kill.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ive restarted ssrs.
2) cancelled the jobs on SSRS reports database.
3) emptied the data table with subscription data in it.
BUT when i look in activity monitor the SSRS subscription is still running threads and i can see that it is exactly the same sql as entered into the SSRS report that is part of the subscription... In a nut shell, everything is first pumped into memory and the subscription will keep running until all the data in memory has been processed through the SSRS system/ even though you have cancelled the running SSRS job.